# join two text files in bash to get output as matching both two columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

Need to join these two TXT into one as below in Bash script. Can you please help

Students TXT File

```
123456 John Doe
345678 John P. Doe
987654 John Public Doe
```

Courses Txt file

```
EECS2021 John Doe
EECS2021 John P. Doe
EECS2031 John Doe
EECS4201 John Doe
```

final TXT should contain person and allocated courses for him.
example:-

```
Person          courses
John Doe        EECS2021 | EECS2031 | EECS4201
John P. Doe     EECS2021 
John Public Doe NoCourses
```

i tried this script and still coudn't get an output.

```
#!/bin/sh
persons=`cat T1.txt`
courses=`cat T2.txt`
echo "$persons"
echo "$courses"
linecountf1=$(wc -l T1.txt | awk '{print $1}')
linecountf2=$(wc -l T2.txt | awk '{print $1}')
i=1
y=1

echo "$persons" | while read line
do
   name1=$(cat T1.txt | awk -F" " '{print $2" " $3" " $4" " $5" " $6}' | sed -n '$i p')
   while [ $linecountf1 = $linecountf2 ]
   do
        name2=$(cat T2.txt | awk -F" " '{print $2" " $3" " $4" " $5" " $6}' | sed -n '$y p')
        if [ "$name1" = "$name2" ]
                then
                        echo "It matching"
                        gdc=$(cat T2.txt | awk -F" " '{print $1}' | sed -n '$i p')
                fi
   done
done



echo "John Doe Registered courses - $gdc"
echo "John P. Doe Registered courses -"
echo "John Public Doe Registered courses -"
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please indicate what you already tried and where you got stuck, and which tools are at you disposal.. That way you can prevent that contributors propose a solution you already know wouldn't work.

Comment: ok i added! thanks

Comment: Thank you. As an additional question, what is the delimiter in the files? Simply space, or TAB (or combinations of those)? Also what should the output order be?

Comment: simply it has spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the output order doesn't matter, the following `awk` program should work:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sub(/^[^ ]* +/,""); courses[$0]; if (length($0)>max) max=length($0); next}
     {course=$1; sub(/^[^ ]* +/,"");
      if (courses[$0]) courses[$0]=courses[$0] " | " course; else courses[$0]=course}
     END{
       printf "%- *s Courses\n",max, "Person";
       for (p in courses) {printf "%- *s %s\n",max,p,courses[p] ? courses[p] : "NoCourses"}
     }' students.txt courses.txt
```

For your input examples, it would produce (on GNU `awk`):

```
Person          Courses
John Public Doe NoCourses
John P. Doe     EECS2021
John Doe        EECS2021 | EECS2031 | EECS4201
```

**Explanation**

- While processing the first file - indicated by `FNR`, the per-file line-counter, being equal to `NR`, the global line counter - we simply populate an array `courses` where the "index" is the student name, and the value remains empty yet. For that purpose, we eliminate the student ID from the line using the `sub()` function so that only the student name remains (`$0` now only contains the student name) - this is necessary because the student name can contain an arbitrary number of spaces, so the usual "field-splitting at space" doesn't help us extract the name.

  At the same time, record the longest name length in `max` in order to prettify the output later.
- While processing the second file, save the course number (the first space-separated field) in a temporary variable `course`, and then again eliminate it from the line so that only the student name remains. Then, look the student name up in the `courses` array, and if there is already an associated value (i.e. `courses[$0]` is not empty), append the course name to the existing value, separated by `|`. Otherwise, set the value to the current course name.
- After both files have been processed (condition `END`), print the column titles - formatted to accomodate the longest student name - and then iterate over the student-courses-array and print the student name and associated courses for each entry (`for (p in courses)` means iterate over all "array indices" = student names in `courses`; this is the part where I cannot guarantee the output order - depending on your `awk` version).